# gRPC protobuf file setup for golang and node

Tags: node.js, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to get a project going with gRPC that has the servers written in golang and the clients written in node

I have a protobuf file structure like this

```
- $GOPATH/src/company/api
  |- server
     |- svc1
        |- svc1.proto
     |- svc2
        |- svc2.proto
  |- hardware
     |- hardware1
        |- hardware1.proto
     |- hardware2
        |- hardware2.proto
  |- lib
     |- used-by-both
        |- used-by-both.proto
```

When defining a service that uses something in the lib directory, I use `-I$GOPATH/src` then import using `import "company/api/lib/used-by-both";` in the proto file and that seems to work **for golang** when I generate everything.

However, when I generate the node files, the import paths in the packages that depend on files from `lib` to be incorrect when the while `api` directory is installed as a node module

If I try to make the `-I` option for the compiler more specific and shorten the `import` statement, the golang package import gets messed up

Any advice on how best to compile these proto files in order to make use of them easliy as go packages **and** node modules?

Comment: you will need to pass code example in order to spot the issue, have a look at this tutorial, hopefully you will spot the issue on your own: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-grpc/ . There is nice lib for web browser that supports node, but have not tried it yet: https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web

Comment: I believe you can specify the option `option go_package = "foo";` in your go project to get the correct package name.  Also, You can specify multiple `-I` paths that include both directories.